# Vim: `set formatoptions` being lost?

Tags: vim

I've got `set formatoptions=cqn` in my `vimrc`, but for some reason it doesn't stick. It seems like Vim is reverting to the default (`fo=tcq`) at some point… But I can't figure out why. Running `-V100/tmp/log` just gives me:

```
formatoptions=tcq
  Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

With no useful context.

So, is there any way to make formatoptions stick? Or do I just need to create an autocmd to reset it each time a new file is loaded?

**Edit**

Using `:verbose set formatoptions` shows this:

```
formatoptions=tcq
  Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

However, the only reference to `fo` or `formatoptions` in my ~/.vimrc is `set formatoptions+=cqn`.

Comment: For now, I'm using `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * setlocal formatoptions+=cqn`

Comment: Does your `.vimrc` source a system wide `vimrc` (usually `/etc/vimrc`), which might have this option?

Comment: Nope — I've checked the system vimrc and it doesn't set formatoptions. Additionally, if it did, I would expect the `set formatoptions` to show up in the verbose log produced by `-V100/tmp/log`.

Comment: [This](http://peox.net/articles/vimconfig.html) may be what you are seeking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the vim documentation on `formatoptions`:

> NOTE: This option is set to the Vi
>   default value when 'compatible' is
>   set and to the Vim default value when
>   'compatible' is reset.

So if the value of compatible is changing along the way, that could be causing the issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 21):

This behavior is because of C file plugin in VIM. Since file plugin is loaded after loading .vimrc, the settings in .vimrc are overwritten.
The solution given by David Wolever seems to be the best option.
Add the following line in .vimrc:

> ```
> autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * setlocal formatoptions+=cqn
> ```

...instead of the normal `set formatoptions` command.

Comment: It works, when you remove the space between BufNewFile and BufRead.

Comment: This answer didn't quite work for me, but a twist on it did, [see my answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23326474/207894).

Answer (score 7):

I ran across this problem too.  I had project-specific configurations something like

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile project/*.c setlocal formatoptions-=cro
```

However, `set fo?` showed `formatoptions=croql`. Turns out, I needed `BufWinEnter` instead of `BufRead`:

> After a buffer is displayed in a window.  This
>   can be when the buffer is loaded (after
>   processing the modelines) or when a hidden
>   buffer is displayed in a window (and is no
>   longer hidden).
>   Does not happen for :split without
>   arguments, since you keep editing the same
>   buffer, or ":split" with a file that's already
>   open in a window, because it re-uses an
>   existing buffer.  But it does happen for a
>   ":split" with the name of the current buffer,
>   since it reloads that buffer.

So this works

```
autocmd BufWinEnter,BufNewFile project/*.c setlocal formatoptions-=cro
```

Answer (score 4):

I does sound like some file either sourced from your .vimrc or plugins are changing that value.

Something to try to pinpoint it is

start vim without sourcing anything, use

```
vim -u NONE
```

Using `NORC` skipps .vimrc but loads plugins

Check `:help --noplugin` to read about various startup-options that controls the sourcing.

```
--noplugin      Skip loading plugins.  Resets the 'loadplugins' option.
                {not in Vi}
                Note that the |-u| argument may also disable loading plugins:
                        argument        load vimrc files        load plugins ~
                        (nothing)               yes                 yes
                        -u NONE                 no                  no
                        -u NORC                 no                  yes
                        --noplugin              yes                 no
```

Perhaps this might be useful as well (from `help: :set`):

```
When 'verbose' is non-zero, displaying an option value will also tell where it
was last set.  Example: >
        :verbose set shiftwidth cindent?
<         shiftwidth=4 ~
                  Last set from modeline ~
          cindent ~
                  Last set from /usr/local/share/vim/vim60/ftplugin/c.vim ~
```

perhaps... :-)

**Edit**

Are you using `compatible`? From `help: formatoptions`

```
    NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
    set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
```

Comment: strange... just a thought, since the variable has its default value, what happens if you place it in a different location in .vimrc? i.e. if at the end now, place it at the top. No if-statement or any dependency in .vimrc?

Answer (score 0):

Found in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/vim.vim`:

```
" Set 'formatoptions' to break comment lines but not other lines,<br>
" and insert the comment leader when hitting <CR> or using "o".<br>
setlocal fo-=t fo+=croql
```

**Remove it.**  Then all things done.

Comment: So why are you using Chinese at this English site?