# Prevent (g)vim from auto-indenting comments

Tags: vim, auto-indent

A while ago, I had to put

```
filetype plugin on
```

in my .vimrc for a plugin I use.

But this caused a change in autoindent: Whenever I write a comment "//", and then press enter, vim autoindentation automatically enters another "//" in the next line.

```
// This is a comment. <ENTER>
// <-- vim automatically puts '// ' there
```

What can I do to avoid this?
I use the autoindent setting in my vim file.
I already tried

```
filetype plugin indent off
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at `:h formatoptions` and `:h fo-table`. The options you need to turn off are `r` and `o`.  Turning them off prevents vim from automatically inserting the comment leader (in this case "//") when you press enter in insert mode or when you press `o` or `O` in normal mode.

Comment: "set formatoptions=-or" did not work actually, even though the documentation says so. I am using "set formatoptions=tnq" now. Thanks!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076592/vim-set-formatoptions-being-lost was useful, as well.

Comment: @knub `set formatoptions-=o | set formatoptions-=r` is the syntax that works for removing options. `set formatoptions-=ro` works only if they are consecutive in the options string as "ro" exactly.

Answer (score 20):

I am answering your title rather than the body of your question, since your title brings people to this page who are looking to stop Vim from indenting comments.

The variable that controls whether Vim auto-indents a new character is `indentkeys`. I've noticed incorrect indentation only in Python and Yaml, so I've turned off auto-indentation only for the "#" character at the beginning of the line: `:set indentkeys-=0#`

Since loading the filetype indentation plugin will override any .vimrc settings you've made, you can set up an `autocmd` to change the indentkeys after a file is created or loaded. Here are mine:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost * if &filetype == "python" | set indentkeys-=0# | endif
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost * if &filetype == "yaml" | set expandtab shiftwidth=2 indentkeys-=0# | endif
```

In the comments Denilson pointed out a way that is simpler and may work better (but I can't currently reproduce the problem):

```
autocmd FileType yaml,python setlocal indentkeys-=0#
```

See [:h indentkeys](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27indentkeys%27)

Note that because of (possibly) a bug, if you use Neovim you must also specify `filetype plugin indent on`, or the filetype won't be set.

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer.  The title brought me here, and it works with my version of vim.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (vim 9.0). By the time the autocmd is executed, the filetype is not yet set. I have instead to use this: `autocmd FileType yaml,nginx,gitconfig setlocal indentkeys-=0#`, use this to find which filetypes override that variable: `grep -E -R '(indentkeys|indk).*0#' --color=always /usr/share/vim | grep -v -- '-=' | sort`

Answer (score 6):

See `:help 'formatoptions'` - I know how annoying this is!

Try this:

```
:set fo-=or
```

Comment: I actually like that feature.  Every so often I have to hunt for this setting again to turn it _on_. :-)