# Vim formatoptions-=or

Tags: vim

I have the following lines in my vimrc:

```
" Don't add the comment prefix when I hit enter or o/O on a comment line.
set formatoptions-=or
```

It used to work at some point. I don't know what I did but it doesn't anymore, I still get comments when creating newlines. What could have disabled it? Here's my vimrc: http://pastebin.com/kVWWeQWW

Comment: Related: [How can I get vim to stop putting comments in front of new lines?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/1983/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you found that the flag `o` is being inserted back in `formatoptions` after startup, you should find out why this is happening and fix it. This seems cleaner than always executing an `autocmd`, even after the option is removed.

You could check where the option is set issuing with following commands:

```
:5verbose set fo?
:5verbose setl fo?
```

---

**Edit:**

If your problem is with a `ftplugin` file that lies on Vim directory (`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin`) you shouldn't change that file, because that change would be undone when Vim is updated. The proper way to change it is in your `after` directory, as explained in `:h after-directory`.

Supposing that the problem occurs with `c` filetype, create file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` containing your `setlocal formatoptions-=` commands.

Comment: It is added every time a file is opened. How can I know what enables it? There's nothing else in my vimrc changing the formatoptions.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. Yeah, I had. But I hadn't removed the `autocmd` line. I've just done it and this time your command led me to the culprit which is `ftplugin`. Thanks!

Comment: The configuration can be changed by many other places beyond your `.vimrc` -- on ftplugins, for instance. If you disable your fix based on `autocmds` and enter in a buffer where `:set formatoptions?` displays the `o` option, issuing the commads above should display something like "Last set from <filename>", then you could understand what enables it.

Comment: Edit: actually, I had a `vimOutliner` file in my ~/.vim/ftplugin folder so the first thing I did was to uninstall it. But the problem remained because the problem indeed came from a `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin`. Since the problem happens in almost every code file I'm editing maybe the `autocmd` is the best choice after all? What do you think?

Comment: If you change `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin` your changes will be lost if Vim is updated and/or if you change to another machine, even if you copy your `.vim` and `.vimrc`. The solution I proposed on the edit is better because it avoid these problems, and can be used to include further customization to each filetype in the recommended way (see `:h after-directory` and http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.6)

Answer (score 15):

@mm2703 's solution didn't work for me, especially for java files, but this change did. I also wrapped it in an `augroup`, statement so resourcing `.vimrc` won't re-register the `autocmd`:

```
augroup Format-Options
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * setlocal formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o

    " This can be done as well instead of the previous line, for setting formatoptions as you choose:
    autocmd BufEnter * setlocal formatoptions=crqn2l1j
augroup END
```

Comment: Ugh, this finally did it. I think I tried 4 answers before getting here. _Thank you._

Answer (score 10):

If your `'formatoptions'` contains options in different order, like `ro`, then `-=or` won't work. Try

```
set formatoptions-=o
set formatoptions-=r
```

From `help remove-option-flags`:

> Note that you should add or remove one flag at a time.  If 'guioptions' has the value "ab", using "set guioptions-=ba" won't work, because the string "ba" doesn't appear.

Comment: It wasn't that either :( Thanks though.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks. Note, you can also do this in a single line: `set formatoptions-=o formatoptions-=r`

Comment: I found this solution is effective in neovim. You may see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76259118/21247237) for details.

Answer (score 6):

I realized with `:set formatoptions?` that although the `o` flag was disabled at startup, it came back when opening a file. This in my vimrc fixed it:

```
" Don't add the comment prefix when I hit enter or o/O on a comment line.
autocmd FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this worked for me - but I'm disabling annoying formatting features...

```html
autocmd!
autocmd BufEnter * setlocal formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=q formatoptions-=n formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o formatoptions-=l
```

Seems like vimrc just ignores the combined syntax, eg. formatoptions-=cqn