# Vim removing "r" from format options for ALL filetypes

Tags: vim

I have found via `:verbose set fo` that

```
formatoptions=a1njwcroql
  Last set from /usr/local/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/vim.vim
```

This is helpful but I obviously can't touch that file.

So, rather than using the unsavory hammer `autocmd`, I am to do something in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16035812/340947).

However I want my adjustment to apply across all filetypes unless I specify otherwise. There is no way in hell I'm going to generate one `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/*.vim` for each language and maintain that, that is far worse than the autocmd.

So hopefully there is something really basic I am missing that I can use *to override Vim's default ftplugin overrides*, namely, where I can run `:set fo-=r` where it will actually do something, because doing it in the `~/.vimrc` does not work (the Vim default ftplugin overrides it (inconsistently between languages, I might add).

To clarify:

1. My vimrc sets `formatoptions` to a reasonable default that I decided upon ahead of time, this happens to be `caq1njw`
2. Vim decides for whatever historical or other reason that *e.g. for the Vim filetype* what we want is `setlocal fo-=t fo+=croql` in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/vim.vim`
3. I am now wanting to override `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/vim.vim`'s override further, with the statement `setlocal fo-=r` (not using an autocmd, I know how to do that).

Comment: Why don't you want to use an autocmd?

Comment: Perfectionism? Is that a valid reason? Fine... *grumble grumble*

Comment: Yes its a valid reason. I was just curious. (I don't know anyway to do it off the top of my head without an autocmd)

Comment: I'm not sure if some "better" method would be any sort of improvement (It might not if it involves another external script to execute), but I would hope that eliminating some auto commands could prevent slowdown better. It took me a while to trim down my vim environment so that it's responsive enough not to drive me nuts when running on Raspberry Pi. This single item should not pose a problem though and I would gladly trade 50ms of startup time for it. Maybe even 50ms in buffer load time! That's how much `fo+=r` gets in the way (causing me to backspace over comment headers)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic autocmd I'm using now, that will have to suffice if there isn't a "right way":

`au BufEnter * setlocal fo-=r`

Seems to work well enough.

Comment: I'd suggest "filetype" rather than "bufenter". No need for it to fire every time you switch buffers or windows!