# Neovim vim.opt:remove doesn't actually change the option

Tags: format, neovim, ftplugin

I came across some problem in my neovim settings, and something weird happens when I use vim.opt:remove to change the `formatoptions`.

First, my default `formatoptions` is `jcroql`, because I run `:verbose set formatoptions?` and it returns:

```
  formatoptions=jcroql
        Last set from /usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/lua.vim line 18
```

Then, I want to change it, removing `ro` options. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030639/vim-formatoptions-or/16035812#16035812), I should use after-directories to change this option.

So, I create a file `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/lua.lua` to change this option for lua files. And here comes the question.

I wrote in this file:

```lua
vim.opt.formatoptions:remove('ro')
-- vim.cmd([[set fo-=ro]])
```

Using neovim lua api to change `formatoptions`, I found

```
  formatoptions=ojqlcr
        Last set from Lua
```

The order and modifier changes, but `ro` is still in formatoptions.

Using native way to change `formatoptions`, aka,

```lua
-- vim.opt.formatoptions:remove('ro')
vim.cmd([[set fo-=ro]])
```

I found:

```
  formatoptions=jcql
        Last set from Lua
```

And it works.

---

Why `vim.opt.formatoptions:remove` doesn't behave what is descriped in it's document? I expect `vim.opt.formatoptions:remove('ro')` is equal to `set fo-=ro` in vim script.

Additionally, is there a way to globally remove `ro` in all filetypes' `formatoptions` using after-directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16032415/21247237), I tried to use separated `remove` calls like this:

```lua
-- vim.opt.formatoptions:remove('ro')
vim.opt.formatoptions:remove("r")
vim.opt.formatoptions:remove("o")
-- vim.cmd([[set fo-=ro]])
```

And now this works! I found `:verbose set formatoptions?` to be:

```
  formatoptions=jclq
        Last set from Lua
```

Although the default `formatoptions` is `jcroql`, including a `ro` in middle. I found that `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/lua.vim line 18` is

```
setlocal formatoptions-=t formatoptions+=croql
```

Maybe it's just a coincidence to see `jcroql` in the `formatoptions`.

Comment: I tried this exact thing, but it's not working for me. `ftplugin/lua.vim` is still updating the `formatoptions` last!